# Why does innerWidth() give different result than get(0).width?

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

Testing in Chrome. If I create dynamically a canvas object, put it into a div like this:

```
$('<div />').css({
    width: '95%',
    margin: '0px auto',
    border: '1px solid red'
})
.append(
    $('<canvas />')
        .attr({ id: 'myCanvas' })
        .css({ width: '100%' })
)
.appendTo('body');
```

And then in all the resize events, i try to show size:

```
function updateCanvas() {
    console.log($('#mycanvas').get(0).width);
    console.log($('#mycanvas').innerWidth());
}

/* listening to whatever change it can be on the device */
var eventListen = function() {
    window.addEventListener("orientationchange", eventResize, false);
    window.addEventListener("resize", eventResize, false);
};
var eventResize = function() {
    window.removeEventListener("orientationchange", eventResize, false);
    window.removeEventListener("resize", eventResize);
    window.setTimeout(function(){
        /* small timeout in case of lot of resize (dragging) */
        var w=innerWidth;
        var h=innerHeight;
        window.setTimeout(function(){
            if ((innerWidth!=w) || (innerHeight!=h)) {
                eventResize();
            } else {
                updateCanvas();
                eventListen();
            }
        }, 100);
    }, 100);
}
eventListen();
```

The results are differents! Pure DOM gives me actual size of the canvas, whereas `$('#mycanvas').innerWidth()` gives me bigger result...

Comment: How does it compare to `.get(0).innerWidth`?

Comment: @Barmar  `$('#mycanvas').get(0).innerWidth` gives me `undefined`. I think it's because `get(0)` returns a canvas object. If I try `console.log($('#mycanvas').get(0))` i get `<canvas id=​"myCanvas" width=​"792px" height=​"376px" style=​"width:​ 100%;​">​`

Comment: You should be setting the attribute width and not the css style width as that is what the canvas will use in its coordinate space, using css width/height will potentially stretch the canvas. Also the canvas [default width/height attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html5-author-20120329/the-canvas-element.html#the-canvas-element) are 300x150:

Comment: You have a width attribute, and a width style, I'm going to guess jQuery will use the computed style and get the exact, correct figure, while you're just getting the HTML attributes value which is being overriden by the CSS.

Comment: @scragar From my 4hours experimentation this may seem the opposite: jQuery stays on the CSS property whereas get(0) gives me the actual size of the object an thus I can center properly my objects. I've just tested: this works perfectly with latest Opera, IE, Firefox & Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this scheme should answer your question (found on google images)

[image]
<sub>(source: [stacktrace.jp](http://stacktrace.jp/jquery/api/css/img/dimensions_width.png))</sub>

The difference between the width and the innerWidth is made by the padding.

**EDIT: Correction**

As PE pointed out, this difference is due to the fact that the width() method you are using is in fact the object property, which is different from the css property.
If you don't set your canvas property the width attribute defaults to 300, and the height attribute defaults to 150. The width and height CSS properties control the size that the element displays on screen.

More info:
http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/scripting.html#attr-canvas-width

Comment: No, OP is not using `width()`, they are using the canvas' object's width property, which is bound to the width attribute on the element. That is not changed by a css style. innerWidth() calculates the width based of the elements layout size after css styles have been applied.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is because you are checking two different things

`get(0).width` is the canvas' object's width property, which is not affected/changed by css styling, and is set either by the element's width attribute or the .width property in js. And defaults to 300x150 as per [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html5-author-20120329/the-canvas-element.html#the-canvas-element).

jQuery's `width()`,`innerWidth()` etc methods are calculating the layout size of the canvas element, which is affected by the css styling.